# Firebase Flutter Dart :Class '_JsonQuerySnapshot' has no instance method '[]'. Receiver: Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'

Tags: json, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying the following:

```
StreamBuilder(
                  stream: user
                          .where('Phone Number',
                              isEqualTo: widget.user['ID'])
                          .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Text("Loading");
                    }
                    var profile= snapshot.data;
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                      child: Text(
                        "${profile["Gender"]}.",
                       
                      ),
                    );
              }),
```

> Class _JsonQuerySnapshot has no instance method '[]'. Receiver:
> Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot' Tried calling: [] ("Gender")

How can I fix this Error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function .snapshots() should return a QuerySnapshot. try accessing snapshot.data.docs and you should get a List which you can then access each QueryDocumentSnapshot data using doc.data().

it'll look something like that:

```
StreamBuilder(
                  stream: user
                          .where('Phone Number',
                              isEqualTo: widget.user['ID'])
                          .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Text("Loading");
                    }
                    // snapshot.data is QuerySnapshot than I access .docs to get List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>
                    var docs = snapshot.data.docs;
                    // Accessing single QueryDocumentSnapshot and then using .data() getting its map.
                    final user = docs[0].data()!;
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                      child: Text(
                        "${user["Gender"]}.",
                       
                      ),
                    );
              }),
```

If it doesn't work let me know and ill update the answer! :)